# Getting interim results from lapply()

Tags: r, save, lapply, environment

I have some lapply code which takes a really long while to compute. Something like this:

```
n <- 10^7
res <- lapply(1:n, function(i){
  print(round(i/n*100, 0))
  rnorm(100)
  })
```

Can we somehow save the interim results while `round(i/n*100, 0)` is less then 100%, i.e. the code is still running?

I am running the my actual `lapply()` code right now and the part `print(round(i/n*100, 0))` tells me that my computer is almost done (99%!). The problem is that I need to turn off the computer because I leave my work place. Is there any chance to get the data R has calculated so far while the `res <- lapply(...)` part is still running? Really don`t want him to calculate for ages those 99% tomorrow again..

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead and write a interim result to disk at every iteration.

Comment: @GregorThomas That is an idea for the next time..

Comment: Yes, if your code is already running then it's too late to change it.

Comment: If you halt execution of a `for` loop, the state will exist where it was interrupted, but if you halt execution of `lapply` any un-returned results will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the `lapply()` code runs there seems to be no way to catch the interim results. But there are two options

- using a `for` loop as suggested by @GregorThomas
- using `<<-` inside the `lapply()` function which does save interim results.

Here is the second option for the piece of code in the question:

```
n <- 10^7
res <- vector("list", n)
res <- lapply(1:n, function(i){
  print(round(i/n*100, 0))
  res[[i]] <<- rnorm(100)
})
```

Now we can have a look and see that the interim data is actually saved:

```
head(res)
tail(res)
```